# How does this entry setting work?

Tags: webpack

I'm using `react-hot-loader`, and it has this setting in its `webpack.config.js`:

```
entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './scripts/index' // Your appʼs entry point
]
```

However, in webpack's doc, I only find this kind of setting:

```
 entry: {
    app: ["webpack/hot/dev-server", "./app/main.js"]
  }
```

Question:

- What's the difference between `webpack/hot/dev-server` and `webpack/hot/only-dev-server`?
- What is the first line? Is `webpack-dev-server` equal to `webpack/hot/dev-server`? And then what is the `client`, and why it has to be bound to a localhost address? Finally why do you need 2 `dev-server` -- is the second one just for hot module reloading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How live reload and HMR works in webpack

webpack-dev-server's solution is based on socket.io. It implements a socket-io server and notifies the client by sending messages whenever it detects a change in source files. It also provides a socket.io client library that connects to the server and provides the logic around how to handle messages coming from server (e.g. reloading the page, or applying hot module replacements).

[webpack-dev-server/client/index.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/v1.10.1/client/index.js) is the file that contains the client library code and some of the message handlers. If server and client are running on different URLs we can configure the client with correct server URL by using [query parameters](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/v1.10.1/client/index.js#L4).

So, in your webpack configuration what is happening is that we are telling webpack to embed this file into our bundle and connect to socket.io server (i.e. webpack-dev-server) that is running on http://localhost:3000/

*As a side note, it is also this file that is embedded into our bundle automatically when we run `webpack-dev-server --inline`.*

### Why need two servers?

The main use case for webpack-dev-server is to serve our bundled assets with it. If our application is just a static html file then it could also be used to serve our application at the same time. When webpack-dev-server is used this way, we wouldn't need two servers running. Even though this is a simpler setup than using two servers it doesn't really reflect real life. Normally our applications are running on a more sophisticated server than a static http server (e.g. Rails, Django, etc).

As a result we separate these concerns and use webpack-dev-server to just serve our bundles on a URL (e.g. http://localhost:3000) and run our application on a different URL (e.g. http://localhost:8080).

### dev-server and only-dev-server

If you open [`dev-server.js`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v1.11.0/hot/dev-server.js) and [`only-dev-server.js`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v1.11.0/hot/only-dev-server.js) side-by-side you will notice that there is little difference between these files.

According to [webpack documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html#what-can-i-do-with-it) the difference between these two is that `dev-server` provides a default fallback mechanism (i.e. reloading the page when HMR fails for some reason) whereas `only-dev-server` doesn't have this behaviour. I guess this allows developers to implement their own way of handling HMR failures.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification. webpack is so much more complex than browserify and I had a hard time digesting all the docs.

Comment: I also don't find webpack's docs very helpful. It is one of these libraries that the only way to really understand what is going is to debug the code line-by-line. Docs become more useful to fill in the gaps.